# Local SQL Server 2008 R2 database not accessible on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, sql-server-2008r2-express

I've inherited the job of maintaining an application which uses a local **SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Express** database as a back-end. I successfully installed the application some months back after upgrading to **Windows 10** so that I could start testing and development, but after reformatting recently, I've been unable to get the database running. I'm using the exact same installer, and so far as I can tell, everything else configuration-wise is the same, with the exception that I'm now on a newer W10 insider build.

The application installer installs SQL Server 2008 R2 with the following parameters:

```
/TCPENABLED=1 /ACTION="INSTALL"  /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="automatic" 
/SECURITYMODE="SQL" /SAPWD="password" /INSTANCENAME="app" 
/FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION  /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" 
/SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS 
/INDICATEPROGRESS /QS
```

The installer is built using Advanced Installer, and is configured to run a database setup script after installation has completed, but when it reaches this step the database times out and the install fails. To test the database I tried using a UDL file, and though the database itself is visible, when I attempt to test the connection I get

> "Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
>   [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or
>   access denied."

I've tried absolutely everything I can think of to fix this problem. I've removed all traces of every version of SQL Server from my computer, purged the registry of any remaining keys, and deleted any remaining directories. I've checked and restarted all SQL services, tried different SQL service accounts, different versions of the SQL installer, ran the installer(s) as an administrator, ran them in compatibility mode, and checked log files. I haven't found anything helpful on StackOverflow or on Advanced Installer's forums. Nothing's worked, and I'm completely out of ideas at this point.

Comment: Contact our tech team on support at advancedinstaller dot com. They will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

According the MS only SQL server 2012 SP2 and up are compatible with Windows 10.

You might try this instruction to install SQL express 2008 R2, but I never tried it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUCbvfFEO34

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately upgrading isn't an option, at least for now.

Comment: I actually did manage to solve the issue though. For anyone who comes across this: it seems to have been caused by an old bug with SQL Server 2008 interacting with some aspect of my Windows configuration. Apparently installing a SQL Server 2008 instance with the currently logged in user as an admin will throw an error, but this only occurred for me when uninstalling and reinstalling.

I haven't found a command line workaround, but installing SQL Server with the full UI and just removing my user account from the administrators field while adding the Administrators group did the trick.

Comment: Glad you could find the problem and thanks for sharing it with us!